# Transaction does not Rollback on Constraint Viollation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Tech Stack -  Hibernate, Spring boot 1.5.10, Mysql

```
@Component("A")
Class A {

  @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
  public void process() {

    User user = new User()
    dao.persist(user);

    Employee e = new Employee ()
    dao.persist(e);
  }

Class Dao {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public void persist(Object o) throws Exception {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(o);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Constant violation occurred while persist the employee object. 
Expected behavior should be that rollback entire DB stuff (should not persist user object).
```

Currently it's inserting the user record successfully even though constraint violation occurred while persisting the employee object.

I used the transaction attribute of method level.

Any hint to rollback entire transaction on constraint violation.

Comment: who calls ```process()```?

Comment: MySql with MyISAM tables instead of InnoDB tables. Switch the engine of MyuSQL to InnoDB.

Comment: Non Transaction method call process method. Spring will start new transaction and should be completed when process method ends

Comment: I have modified hibernate property like   hibernatePropertiesCacheable.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"); hibernatePropertiesCacheable.setProperty("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine", "innodb");

Comment: As i'm looking at Spring code on debug mode and  public void beforeCommit(boolean readOnly) throws DataAccessException {
        if(!readOnly) {
            Session session = this.getCurrentSession();
            if(!FlushMode.MANUAL.equals(SessionFactoryUtils.getFlushMode(session))) {
                SessionFactoryUtils.flush(this.getCurrentSession(), true);
            }
        }

    }

Comment: First persist query executed and save the record in DB but second insert failed due to constraint violation. Than after transaction marked as rollback and  use session.clear() called. I could not find anywhere in spring will delete the record which has inserted before constraint violation

Comment: It won't. You are using Spring Boot so you should configure things in `application.properties` not in code.

Comment: I agree.. all these properties defined in application.properties. This will not solve my main issue

Comment: It's good that you're peeking under the hood. You should step through what the persist method actually does. It'll be apparent that your transactional annotations are not being honored.

Comment: transaction annotation is working as expected. Let suppose that getting any exception of creating the employee object or any properyvalue exception. Than everything rollback and working as expected.Issue only in constraint violation.Look at the spring code, it uses flush so first success and second failed. How spring rollback /delete the record which is added before constraint violation

Comment: 1 session.persist() -> flush() -> 2 session.persist() -> exception -> rollback 2

Comment: rollback 2 - > need to manually delete the record created at 1 step.  I want to ask that does spring automatically handle ?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary. Take a look at my answer below

Comment: Spring doesn't delete anything and nor does a transaction that isn't how a transaction works. As stated check your actual tables as I still believe those are MyISAM (don't check your settings check the actual database tables)... If you are using a table type that isn't supporting transactions then it simply won't work. Also don't add additional information / config etc. as comments but modify your question. Please add configuration (java and properties) also you are using Spring Boot why use a session factory then (which basically means you are working around Spring Boot and JPA)!.